# Postgres: How to deal with deprecated hstore operator: "=>"

Tags: r, postgresql, hstore

I have just read that the `=>` operator for the hstore extension [is deprecated and might be removed in future versions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html). This is bad news to because I have several functions in R that
rely on using this operator when storing to Postgres table that contains hstore fields.

I prepare a `data.frame` or `data.table` in memory (R Session) before I write to the database.
Subsequently I just write the entire table in memory to the database by using the convenient function `dbWriteTable`. Hence it would be inconvenient to use the postgres function hstore(text,text).

What is a good strategy to handle such an announcement? I am quite surprised they are removing the operator since there must be quite some people writing to hstore alongside fields of other types. Also this is not really R-specific. It has to be the same issue for many languages..

Though I got some helpful insights so far, maybe this helps to clarify what my problem is:

I added a reproducible example for the R folks and a screenshot for the rest of the world..[image]
I build a data.frame in R (basically a table representation in memory) like this:

```
mydf <- structure(list(ts_key = c("somekey", 
                      "somekey"), ts_language = c("de", "en"
                      ), ts_labels = c("\"Kurztitel\" => \"Wohlbefinden\",\"mögliche_Antworten\" => \"fantastisch,so lala,total fertig\",\"Wortlaut\" => \"Wie geht es?\"", 
                                       "\"available_items\" => \"awesome,somewhat ok,wasted\",\"short_title\" => \"well being\",\"wording\" => \"How are you?\""
                      )), .Names = c("ts_key", "ts_language", "ts_labels"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                          -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

So the memory table / data.frame contains an `hstore` as a character as one of its columns.
This is very convenient because I can have a data.frame with lots of rows and then simply use:

```
dbWriteTable(myconnection,"somePostgresTableWithTheRightStructure",mydf,append=T)
```

and just write the entire data.frame to the db without having to build the query or explicit looping. I'd love to keep this but I just don't know how tell `dbWriteTable` to use hstore(text,text).

Comment: Could you write a wrapper for `=>` and include it in your package as a stopgap until you can migrate your code?

Comment: Currently, everything works. I have this function: https://github.com/mbannert/pgsqltsmap/blob/master/R/create_hstore.R
that creates a character representation, so I can have a data.frame that contains (among others) a hstore column. Is this what you mean? I just don't want to go away from using dbWriteTable and having to create lots of single INSERT.

Comment: I meant basically import the `=>` function to your package, but it seems like from @Denis's comment that it would cause problems with SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not specific to hstore: it affects other custom operators too. The reasoning for its [removal in 9.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release-9-2.html) is that [the SQL standard now reserves that token](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/pgsql-Remove-hstore-s-text-gt-text-operator-td4973123.html).

> What is a good strategy to handle such an announcement?

Consider switching to using json. It has a similar `->` operator, a similar set of functions, and I imagine you've R libraries that allow to go from an object to json and back. At the database-level, the change merely involves a [cast from hstore to json](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) (see the very last note on the json docs' page).

Comment: +1 for helping me to understand the removal and to judge whether that it's going to disappear soon. Indeed R to json and back works quite well in R. What I still don't get is: In order to be able to use my bulk import function I have to write my data.table to the database (to avoid having multiple single INSERT queries). So assume, if it contains `json` instead of the character representation of hstore using `=>`, can I store it to the database at trigger a cast like you suggest afterwards?

Comment: If your table contains a json column such as, you can insert the json's text representation directly in it (provided it's well formed, of course), much like you would for a date or a timestamp. (pseudocode, but you'll hopefully get the point) So, when running something like: `db.query("insert into foo(bar) values ?)", str)`, instead of building an hstore string like `str = 'a=>1'`, you'd build a json object like `str = JSON.new(a: 1).to_s`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have just added a snippet and screenshot to illustrate the problem with `dbWriteTable`. Maybe actually building a JSON string instead, store to pg and then trigger a conversion could be a solution.

Comment: If I understand [the docs](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/DBI/html/dbReadTable.html) correctly, `dbWriteTable()` will generate the SQL statements for you based on the data you give it. So you'd want to build the JSON string, yes, hence the `.to_s` in my pseudocode example. (I can't imagine R not providing something equivalent out of the box given a JSON object.)

Comment: I think the json is really nice. Sure  R does provide an equivalent, but then I store json to postgres. Do you mean I need a second query or even second table field to finally get hstore?

Comment: I was always assuming you understood the suggestion that you ought to change your schema to store JSON instead of hstore. :-( If you want to keep hstore, Peter's suggestion is the correct way to go, though you'll need to use a different function to build the actual insert statements since you'll need to store an expression… If changing datatype is a reasonable option, then my answer is you ought to try JSON, since there's a straightforward and unequivocal means to convert text to JSON that is built-in, allowing you to use the same logic (give or take some tweaks, since it's a different type).

Comment: ok got it, thanks for your patience :). I will explore whether dropping hstore is an option for the team here. Anyway JSON was a great hint in general here – i'll enhance my db mapper package to support JSON storing. I was a little disturbed by the fact that the postgres console returns `"a" => "b"` when I run `hstore(a,b)`.

Answer (score 3):

Only the operator is being removed, not the underlying functionality.  So instead of

```
a => b
```

write

```
hstore(a, b)
```

This is completely backward compatible.  So just change your code today and be done.

Comment: This is just the problem. I have a lot of advantages of using `dbWriteTable` and thus do not want to explicitly run INSERT statements. Need to prepare a string in memory if possible.

Comment: And what is stopping you from doing that?